# What's wrong with my Mythtv install

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql, mythbuntu, mythtv

Here is a link to the start up of my Mythtv Backend. It is not connecting to the database. There is the scrolling terminal window. Can some look at it and tell me what the issue is and possible fix?

[Mythtv Backend Startup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HxgHMBbELw2llrZ9qklLA-8ubblE3Nhp/view?usp=sharing)

[Last 100 lines or so](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D5s-MuTcLKNsj9TzEajUmdjVJyLpQ_H9/view?usp=sharing)

```
lines 1-19/19 (END)...skipping...
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-11-19 21:50:50 CST; 25min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─7760 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           ├─7904 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-log-error --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.p
           └─7905 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error

Nov 19 21:50:49 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:49 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
Nov 19 21:50:49 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:49 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Nov 19 21:50:49 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:49 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.0 started; log sequence number 1616867
Nov 19 21:50:49 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Nov 19 21:50:49 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Nov 19 21:50:50 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: 171119 21:50:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Nov 19 21:50:50 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[7905]: Version: '10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 16.04
Nov 19 21:50:50 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysql[7725]:    ...done.
Nov 19 21:50:50 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Nov 19 21:50:50 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 /etc/mysql/debian-start[7953]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
```

Here is the running printout:

This was at the end.

```
     LINE EDITING

        These keys can be used to edit text being entered 
        on the "command line" at the bottom of the screen.

Cannot write to "ptiPlex-9010 /etc/mysql/debian-start[7953]: Upgrading MySQL tables if nece
  -w  ........  --hilite-unread
                  Highlight first new line after forward-screen.
  -W  ........  --HILITE-UNREAD
                  Highlight first new line after any forward movement.
  -x [N[,...]]  --tabs=[N[,...]]
                  Set tab stops.
  -X  ........  --no-init
                  Don't use termcap init/deinit strings.
  -y [N]  ....  --max-forw-scroll=[N]
                  Forward scroll limit.
  -z [N]  ....  --window=[N]
                  Set size of window.
  -" [c[c]]  .  --quotes=[c[c]]
                  Set shell quote characters.
  -~  ........  --tilde
                  Don't display tildes after end of file.
  -# [N]  ....  --shift=[N]
                  Horizontal scroll amount (0 = one half screen width)
      ........  --no-keypad
                  Don't send termcap keypad init/deinit strings.
      ........  --follow-name
                  The F command changes files if the input file is renamed.
      ........  --use-backslash
                  Subsequent options use backslash as escape char.


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                          LINE EDITING

        These keys can be used to edit text being entered 
        on the "command line" at the bottom of the screen.

 RightArrow ..................... ESC-l ... Move cursor right one character.
 LeftArrow ...................... ESC-h ... Move cursor left one character.
 ctrl-RightArrow  ESC-RightArrow  ESC-w ... Move cursor right one word.
HELP -- Press RETURN for more, or q when done
```

[MySQL error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/114dEnV3AtzNy6RhM4y7qCVEd142T_uT-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possibly the log files (e.g. the last 100 lines or so of 
`/var/log/mythtv/mythbackend.log`) would be more useful than a video capture of your screen

Comment: I've attached a TXT file with the last 100 lines or so.

Comment: Thanks - the thing that stands out is `Access denied for user 'mythtv'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` - is the mysql server running (`service mysql status`)? Can you log in to it from a terminal using `mysql -u mythtv -p mythconverg` with the `DBPassword` that you should find in the `/etc/mythtv/mysql.txt` file?

Comment: Yes able to log into it.

Comment: I did an update to MySQL and attached a file of the error information.

Answer (score 1):

I FINALLY GOT IT!

I got Mythtv 29 working last night. Thanks to steeldriver on the Askubuntu forum and MikeB2013 from the Mythtv forums for some suggestions that pointed me in another direction.

I did set a static IP address for the system. Don’t know if it was needed but it worked.

I had installed Ubuntu and Mythtv so many times, I can do it in my sleep. Part of the problem was that in the deleting of MySQL there were folders and files left behind. I think they may have been interfering with each new installation. So I did a search of the folders and deleted the references to MYSQL and MYTH any where I found them using the terminal. I also deleted full folders with references.

Rebooted the computer.

Installed the PPA for Myth 0.29 and installed Mythtv using the terminal. When done I rebooted again. I then went to the config.xml and wrote down the user and goofy password listed in the file. I then started the Myth backend installation. When it was completed, I started entering information. I used the mythtv user listed in the config.xml, password, static IP and the rest of the information needed. I set up the card, scanned for channels and set a storage folder. I then rebooted. When I started the backend, it said it was connected to the master backend. I finished the installation of the frontend and tried to record but still nothing. It then dawned on me that I had set a record folder in my directory but had never given permissions for myth to access the folder. So I changed that and everything started working. I am able to watch TV and record shows now.

Hopefully someone will update the installation and setup instructions. What is out there does not address everything and is several versions and years old.

Chuck837